# Access current_user in model (or some other workaround)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I've read several SO links on this topic. Even if you can hack it to get current_user in model, you shouldn't do it. So, what are my options in my case?

I'm using the devise_invitable gem, and one of the commands is `User.invite!({:email => email}, current_user)`, which stores who the user is invited by (`current_user`). I'd like to have this information.

Currently, users are invited to join a private group, and this process is handled in my `group.rb` model:

```rb
# group.rb
  def user_emails
  end

  def user_emails=(emails_string)
    emails_string = emails_string.split(%r{,\s*})
    emails_string.each do |email|
      user = User.find_for_authentication(email: email)
      if user
        self.add user
        GroupMailer.welcome_email(user)
      else
        User.invite!(email: email) # But I want this: User.invite!({:email => email}, current_user)
        user = User.order('created_at ASC').last
        self.add user
      end
    end
  end
```

If relevant, it's just a text_area that receives these emails to process:

```rb
# groups/_form.html.erb
<%= f.text_area :user_emails, rows: 4, placeholder: 'Enter email addresses here, separated by comma', class: 'form-control' %>
```

Without having to re-arrange too much, how can I run `User.invite!({:email => email}, current_user)` in this process, so that this useful information (who is invited by whom) is stored in my database? Much thanks!

---

**Update**:

With @Mohamad's help below, I got it working.

```rb
# group.rb
  def emails
  end

  def invite_many(emails, inviter)
    emails.split(%r{,\s*}).each do |email|
      if user = User.find_for_authentication(email: email)
        add user
        GroupMailer.group_invite user
      else
        add User.invite!({:email => email}, inviter)
      end    
    end
  end

# groups_controller.rb
  def update
    @group = Group.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if @group.update_attributes(group_params)
      emails = params[:group][:emails]
      @group.invite_many(emails, current_user) # also put this in #create
      redirect_to @group
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error saving group. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

And then nothing in my User model because User.invite is defined already by devise_invitable and I didn't need to do anything else. This process is working great now!

Comment: How is `invite!` defined? How do you store the user invited? If you do something like `User.invite!(email: email, invited_by: current_user)`, you're not accessing the `current_user` in the model: the model has no idea that `invited_by` is set to `current_user`, only the controller does.

Comment: devise_invitable takes care of all of that. I know I cannot run `User.invite!(email: email, invited_by: current_user)` in the model b/c it doesn't know current_user. I'm just wondering what workaround I could do to get devise_invitable to know who sent the invite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some subtle issues with your code. There's a potential race condition on the `else` branch of your code where you try to add the last created user. I'm also unsure that you need a setter method here unless you are access `emails` from elsewhere in the instance of `Group`.

As suggested by others, pass the current user as an argument form the controller. I'm not sure how `invite!` is implemented, but assuming it returns a user, you can refactor your code considerably.

I would do somethng like this:

```
def invite_many(emails, inviter)
  emails.split(%r{,\s*}).each do |email|
    if user = User.find_for_authentication(email: email)
      add user
      GroupMailer.welcome_email user
    else
      add User.invite!(email, inviter)
    end    
  end
end

# controller
@group.invite_many(emails, current_user)

# User.invite
def invite(email, inviter)
  # create and return the user here, and what else is necessary
end
```

Comment: thank you. I'm now attempting this approach. I changed my `:text_area` to `:emails` to be consistent, and I put `@group.invite_many(emails, current_user)` in controller under both create and update (because a user can invite more users by just editing the group and submitting the form) just after if @group.save... Once it got to that line, it didn't know what 'emails` were, so I changed that to params[:emails], then it goes to invite_many method in model, but didn't know what `emails` was, so it was .split on nilclass. Am I doing this all wrong? Thank you kindly for your guidance.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! and updated what I did above. Thanks again, this is a much cleaner process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `user_emails()` from the controller (and I'm guessing you are as that must be where you are receiving the form to pass in `emails_string`), you can pass in the `current_user`:

`user_emails(emails_string, current_user)`

and change `user_emails` to receive it:

`def user_emails=(emails_string, current_user)`

Answer (score -2):

You can store the current_user with global scope ,like @current_user,which can be assigned in sessions controller,so in model you will just @current_user as the current user of the app.

Comment: never access sesion inside model!